# How do I make VS2015 to use HTTP/2?

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, http2

I tried looking for option to enable `http/2` in Web Project file (`.csproj`), also on `HttpRequest` object without luck. Is it a setting in `web.config` by any chance?

**How do I enable/disable use of HTTP/2 in Visual Studio?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you must have IIS 10 installed, and it's only available on Windows 10.

Then, the only thing you need to do is to turn on the `Enable SSL` label on your Web Application project, and if when you run your localhost to the HTTPS port, it will be automatically running on HTTP/2.

[image: Web Application PrintScreen]

At the time of writing, there is no option for doing that on ASP.NET 5 Web Applications though.

You can grab more information here: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/released-today-visual-studio-2015-asp-net-4-6-asp-net-5-ef-7-previews